# X-editable toggle on click. How to disable native element click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

Problem is that cant disable native "on click" event that triggers x-editable to transform into textarea. I want that only Button could tranfsorm text to textarea, So that on text is non-clickable.

I found questions how to trigger x-editable on other element click.
But how to disable native text click and leave only other element's event ?

Fiddle with problem is here:

This part works great:

```
$('.edit-post-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $textarea = $(this).closest('.media-body').find('.editable');
    $textarea.editable('toggle');        
});
```

But when trying to disable native text click, it wont work, or I'm doing something wrong here ?

```
$('.editable-post-textarea').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('native-click-triggered!');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is sample with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jjdJX/64/

**So how to disable native "click" event on textarea, and leave trigger only on "EDIT TEXT" button?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable elements' click event using:

```
$('.editable-post-textarea').off('click');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjdJX/65/

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't image that it can be solved so easily.

Answer (score 2):

In version 1.5.1 you can set a 'toggle' option with a 'manual' value

```
$('.editable').editable({
  toggle: 'manual'
});
```

Doing this has the nice side effect of removing the dashed-underline decoration in the editable field.

source [official x-editable docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable)